# Error in chol.default(Bmat) : the leading minor of order 34 is not positive definite

Tags: analysis, co

```
library(CCA)
library(plyr)
head(tobacco_clr$data)

table(tobacco_clr$data)
table(tobacco_clr$H)
x <- tobacco_clr$data
dim(x)

H <- tobacco_clr$H
dim(H)
cca.tobacco <- cc(x,H)


Show this result

Error in chol.default(Bmat) : 
  the leading minor of order 34 is not positive definite
```

What is the Solution? Where I make mistake? Please can you solve it? In console it shows that. What code I use for this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You'll need to provide a little more guidance / data. Can you provide `tobacco_clr`? Also, what is the solution you're looking for? Do you just want the code to run without an error message?

Comment: See this for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example